# Given vector b, is vector x in the range of the linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm given a matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&{-4}&7&{-5}\\0&1&{-4}&3\\2&{-6}&6& {-4}\end{pmatrix}$$

I'm asked to find all vectors $x$ in $R^4$ that are mapped onto the zero vector by the transformation $x \to Ax$.

I found the answer to be $$\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\\\end{pmatrix}=c_1\begin{pmatrix}9\\4\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}+c_2\begin{pmatrix}{-7}\\{-3}\\0\\1\\\end{pmatrix}$$

The next question, which I am having trouble with, is

Further, given $b =\begin{matrix} [-1 & 1 & 0]\end{matrix} $, is $x$ in the range of the linear transformation $x \to Ax$?

How do I solve this?

Comment: You are asking to find the null space of $A$. To do that, at least $A$ has four rows because $x\in\mathbb{R}^4$..

Comment: How did you compute the null space of $A$? The common methods to do so also tell you what its column space is.

Comment: @ThE411  Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

The standard way for the second question is to consider the **[augmented matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix)** , with vector $b$ as last column, and perform the Gauss algorithm on it in order to obtain the RREF.

If you obtain a consistent system of equivalent equations then $b$ is a special solution of $Ax=b$.